# Redirect a domain to another domain in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, url, redirect, web-config

I have a website with `two domains` and `one hosting server` that worked fine with this two URL.
domains are `www.jongeshadi.com` and `www.jongeshadi.ir`.
I want when a user typed `www.jongeshadi.ir`redirect to `www.jongeshadi.com`.
I Google it and find some solution such as change web config to:

```
<rewrite>
        <globalRules>
          <rule name="Redirects to www.jomgeshadi.com" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url=".*" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
              <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^jongeshadi.*(ir|com)$" />
              <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www.)?jonsgeshadi.(ir|com)$" />
              <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www.jongeshadi.com$" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.domain.ir/{R:0}" />
          </rule>
        </globalRules>
    </rewrite>
```

But it doesn't worked.any thing is mistake or is there other solution?

Comment: Do you have the URI Rewrite extension installed on your IIS server?

Comment: @Dai ,I'm using a website panel and can't full access to the server.How can i do it?may i ask you more explain about it?

Comment: Make the change in DNS and keep the resources free on your web server.

Comment: @HamidTalebi If you're using a shared webhost then you probably don't have the URI Rewrite extension installed. Contact your webhost to ask for them to install it, otherwise you can't use the `<rewrite>` configuration options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally found a solution ,but it is clear that we have other solutions .

```
<script runat="server" language="c#">
        public void Page_Init(Object Src, EventArgs E)
        {
            switch ((Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_HOST"]).Replace("www.", ""))
            {
                case "jongeshadi.com":                        
                case "jongshadi.ir":                       
                case "jongshadi.com":                       
                default:
                    Response.Redirect("http://www.jongeshadi.ir");
                    break;
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 5):

With modern version of IIS, the easiest way to achieve this is by using *URL Rewrite 2.0*.  It can be installed as a package using Microsoft's [Web Platform Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx).

Once you have the rewrite module installed, it adds a *URL Rewrite* feature in IIS Manager when the website is selected in the tree view.

[image: URL Rewrite in IIS Manager]

Inside the URL Rewrite feature, choose "Add rule(s)..." from the right-hand side bar, and then choose to add a "Canonical domain name" rule.  Specify the primary host name you want to be the one to display and hit OK.

[image: The add rule dialog box]

[image: Selecting your primary host name]

That's all there is to it.